# Highcharts: zooming doesn't show full visible series

Tags: highcharts

When I zoom in on a series in highcharts, I've noticed that the first visible point of the series is where it starts to draw. This means that if the only point in the visible zoomed area is in the middle, then the line for that series only starts to draw in the middle of the window. Is there a way to make Highcharts render the previous value so that it does not "cut off" the previous values of the graph?

Before, zoomed out:
[image: Zoomed out view of the series]

After, zoomed in (problem):
[image: Zoomed in view, problem series in blue]

Desired:
[image: Zoomed in view, problem series in blue]

I have tried setting [cropThreshold and connectNulls](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.connectNulls) (just in case) among other tweaks with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding your problem. Can you clarify what the intended behavior is? It sounds like you want highcharts to jump to the previous data point if the selected zoom area is between data points ?

Comment: That would work, I think you understand. Basically, when I zoom in I want it to plot the full window of the series, rather than plotting from the first visible point onward. That would include connecting the current point to the previous point that is out of the zoomed view (to the left of it), resulting in the last screenshot. Does that help?

Comment: Have you tried to set minRange parameter ? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange

Comment: Is it possible to recreate it as live demo ?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you ever find a solution?  I'm just now encountering this same problem.

Comment: I didn't, no :-(. Glad to hear it's not just me, though!